# Why are DateTime Strings 0-padded On One Windows 10 System, but Not On Most Others?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, parsing

The following code on several machines sets a SQL Server date time string from "NOW" to the same date but at midnight.

```
DateTime deleteDateThreshold = DateTime.Now;
string deleteDateThresholdS = DateTime.Now.ToString();
deleteDateThresholdS = deleteDateThresholdS.Substring(0, 10) + " " + "00:00:00 AM";
```

Come to think of it, I could have probably subtracted back to midnight, but I thought this was a faster way.

Then the string gets parsed into a DateTime; and has one day subtracted from it. One one system, the parse blows up, because the Substring encounters an extra character, value of 2, because the date string is not zero-padded (03/04/2020). I finally was able to capture the offending date time; and it's not a DateTime, so the exception should occur.

Here is the code that parses.

```
deleteDateThreshold = DateTime.Parse(deleteDateThresholdS, us);
deleteDateThreshold = deleteDateThreshold.AddDays(-1);
```

on most systems, the date string looks like this

```
"03/04/2020 00:00:00 AM"
```

However, on the system that throws the exception, the dates are not 0-padded, and the string looks like this:

```
"3/4/2020 2 00:00:00"
```

Why is there a 2 in this string, and why are the month and day not 0-padded?

Comment: If you don't provide a culture ToString an Parse will take the current system culture. If you need to process datetimes or floats as strings always provide a culture (preferably CultureInfo.InvariantCulture which will never change). The only case where you don't want t provide a culture is when you just use the string for display purposes. That aside, I am wondering why you use strings to provide a DateTime to SQLServer. Use prepared statements and provide the DateTime object directly.

Comment: +1 for @ckuri last paragraph. Not having to fight with dates formatted as string in SQL is my #1 reason to use parameters and not string concatenation in queries. #2 is gracefully handling values containing apostrophes. Also parameters offer great protection against SQL Injection, but that's just a small detail :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Come to think of it, I could have probably subtracted back to midnight, but I thought this was a faster way.

I'd say that `<somedate>.Date` or `DateTime.Today` (thanks, @ckuri) is probably the easiest way to get to the (local) midnight for somedate/today. (Perhaps consider using UtcNow throughout all your systems though)

What the true nature of your problem is, I'm not sure at this point but I'm near certain it wouldn't happen if you kept your dates as dates and didn't convert in and out of strings to manipulate them; SQL Server has date datatypes, that map to CLR datatypes - there shouldn't be any need at all to store, process, transit or manipulate a date as a string in this system at all

Comment: The easiest way would be `DateTime.Today`.